# Convert String to DateTime Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a string `"2015-11-01T10:00:00.00+08:00"` extracted from json response. **How can convert it to Time or DateTime?**

I tried `Time.new("2015-11-01T10:00:00.00+08:00")` its returning `2015-01-01 00:00:00 +0530`, clearly the date is changed here and time too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
require 'date'

▶ Date.parse "2015-11-01T10:00:00.00+08:00"
#⇒ #<Date: 2015-11-01 ((2457328j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>

▶ DateTime.parse "2015-11-01T10:00:00.00+08:00"
#⇒ #<DateTime: 2015-11-01T10:00:00+08:00 ((2457328j,7200s,0n),+28800s,2299161j)>
```

or, even better:

```
▶ DateTime.iso8601 "2015-11-01T10:00:00.00+08:00"
#⇒ #<DateTime: 2015-11-01T10:00:00+08:00 ((2457328j,7200s,0n),+28800s,2299161j)>
```

Comment: You dont need to use `require 'date'` first?

Answer (score 3):

With Rails, depending on your needs, it's recommended to use :

```
Time.zone.parse("2015-11-01T10:00:00.00+08:00")
#=> Sun, 01 Nov 2015 02:00:00 UTC +00:00
```

vs

```
Time.parse("2015-11-01T10:00:00.00+08:00")
#=> 2015-11-01 10:00:00 +0800
```

`Time.zone.parse` will return a Datetime expressed in your Timezone.

Answer (score 0):

[`Time#parse`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-parse):

```
require 'time'
Time.parse("2015-11-01T10:00:00.00+08:00")
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's in rails, just do

```
"2015-11-01T10:00:00.00+08:00".to_time
```

worked in rails console.

If it's just plain ruby, go for @mudasobwa's solution